# C# How to show the default Image selector when clicked in a propertygrid?

Tags: c#

I have a class with an Image property. This property is exposed via the propertygrid. I want to show the default image window. How can I do this? And how can I get the selected value?

It is the same functionality as when you choose an Image for a Form. I want to show that window.

Comment: I'm not at a machine, but TypeConverter is the place to start looking...

Answer (score 0):

Try to add next atribute to the Image property

```
[EditorAttribute(typeof(System.Drawing.Design.ImageEditor), typeof(System.Drawing.Design.UITypeEditor))]
```

Comment: Thnx that's it. But where is the image stored? Is the path to the image stored? Or is there created an Image object, or... ?